# Find duplicate fields in a list of list of objects

Tags: java, java-8, duplicates, java-stream

I have an list of objects like so:

```
[{
     supplier: ""
     rating: [{
        sid: "1"
    },
    {
       sid:"1"
    }]
   }]
```

I want to check whether for each rating the sid doesn't have duplicates in Java
The class looks like:

```
class Entity {
  private String supplier;
  private List<Rating> ratings;
}



class Rating {
    String sid;
    String bar;
}
```

Within each `ratings`, there would be no duplicate `sid`

This is saved to mongo via PUT call so I'm not sure if it would be reasonable doing something like in Mongo by means of adding indexes.

**Edit**: The structure is like so

```
List<List<Rating>> dupCheck = ratings.stream().map(p -> p.getRating()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

OR

```
List<Entity>
```

so when I call on this it asks for index which I tried to solve by IntStream but couldn't.

**Update**: Sorry I was not clear. I want to detect duplicates within one entity(on sid field).

```
new Entity("A",
                Arrays.asList(
                        new Rating("1", "a"),
                        new Rating("2", "b"),
                        new Rating("3", "c"),
                        new Rating("1", "d")
                )),
```

So in the above I would want to detect if there is any repeated `sids`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if you have duplicated `sid`s, you can do:

```
List<Entity> entities = Arrays.asList(
        new Entity("A",
                Arrays.asList(
                        new Rating("1", "a"),
                        new Rating("2", "b"),
                        new Rating("3", "c"),
                        new Rating("4", "d")
                )),
        new Entity("B",
                Arrays.asList(
                        new Rating("1", "a"),
                        new Rating("5", "e")
                ))
);


Map<String, Long> sidToCount = entities.stream()
        .map(Entity::getRatings)
        .flatMap(ratings -> ratings.stream().map(Rating::getSid)) // stream of sids
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s, Collectors.counting()));

boolean hasDuplicates = sidToCount.values()
        .stream()
        .anyMatch(count -> count > 1);

System.out.println(hasDuplicates); // true
```

**EDIT:**

To find if an entity has duplicated ratings, you can do:

```
boolean hasEntityWithDuplicates = entities.stream()
        .map(Entity::getRatings)
        .anyMatch(ratings -> ratings.size() > new HashSet<>(ratings).size());
```

By creating a `Set` we can count the number of unique elements. If the size of the set is smaller than the size of the list, it means the list contains duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This would consider the sid within all the flattened values. Could this be tweaked to find duplicates within one entity?

Comment: find if there are duplicates within one entity or return duplicates within one entity?

Comment: Detecting is okay, I want to throw an exception as soon as I detect any duplicates

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash set to find out if your list has duplicates:

```java
Set<String> sids = new HashSet<>();

// `numDuplicates` returns the number of duplicate ratings
long numDuplicates = ratings.stream()
    .map(r -> r.sid)
    // HashSet#add returns `true` if the element was not yet in the HashSet, and `false` if the HashSet already contained the element.
    .filter(s -> !sids.add(s))
    // Count the number of elements already contained.
    // here you could also use `collect` if you want to find out which ratings are duplicated.
    .count();

if (numDuplicates > 0) {
    // there are duplicates
}
```

Comment: Updated post, the list of objects is within main list